# How to pass output from a Datastage Parallel job to input as another job?

Tags: datastage

My requirement is

1. Parallel Job1 --I extract data from a table, when row count is more than 0
2. Parallel job 2 should be triggered in the sequencer only when the row count from source query in Job1 is greater than 0

I want to achieve this without creating any intermediate file in job1.

Comment: Why? What is your requirement to do so?

Comment: Only when the row count from source query in Job1 is greater than 0.Job2 in the sequencer should be triggered .

Answer (score 3):

So basically what you want to do is using information from a data stream (of your Job1) and use it in the "above" sequence as a parameter.

In your case you want to decide on sequence level to run subsequent jobs (if more than 0 rows get returned) or not.

Two options for that:

1. Job1 writes information to a file which is a value file of a parameterset. These files are stored in a fixed directory. The parameter of the value file could then be used in your sequence to decide your further processing. Details for parameter sets can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610390).
2. You could use a server job for Job1 and set a user status (basic function DSSetUserStatus) in a transfomer. This is also passed back to the sequence and could be referenced in subsequent stages of the sequence. See the [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.cliapi.ref.doc/topics/r_common_DSSetUserStatus.html) but you will find many other information on the internet as well regarding this topic.

There are more solution to this problem - or let us call it challenge. Other ways may be a script called at sequence level which queries the database and will avoid Job1...